# Can i send data with this RF wireless transmitter?

Tags: gpio

In an optimistic mood I [bought this one](http://www.miniinthebox.com/nl/rf-wireless-transmitter-module-315-of-433-92-mhz-cdt88_p479822.html), it's a wireless transmitter 433.92Mhz

[image]

At home I have a [set like this](http://www.elro.eu/products/category/home_automation/home_comfort/sets/3_schakelaars_met_afstandsbediening1) that uses 433Mhz to remotely switch devices on and off.

[image]

Before the Pi I was programming on the Fez Panda and for that device I have found some code how to control the wireless transmitter. I couldn't find it for the Pi.

Now my question is: is it even possible to control this transmitter via the Pi?

Comment: The answer is Yes. The Pi can transmit data using that. The problem is what data? Did you ever get the remote switch to turn on and off using a `Fez Panda` ?

Comment: Well, to be honoust, i didn't try it via the Fez Panda, it's now in use in my living room doing measurements. But to answer your question: the sample code (http://wiki.tinyclr.com/index.php?title=FEZ_RF433) sends a arrayList of integers to a OutputCompare, which is, from the docs: "OutputCompare (OC) is non-blocking digital waveform generator. When you need to generate a digital waveform, you need the state of a pin to change very quickly and this has to be done in real time. "

Comment: OK. So what what do you need to send to turn 1 remote switch ON. What command, string, integer array of waveform will turn Switch 1 ON? If you do not know the answer to that then you cannot achieve your goal ever. Remember some of these switches use DES/AES encryption and just seeing the signal will be different each time. But most of the time they are unencrypted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I can't make any guarantees but it looks very much like the stuff used in [this article](http://www.hoagieshouse.com/RaspberryPi/RCSockets/RCPlug.html) .

In my case the [transmitter was this one](http://www.kjell.com/sortiment/el/elektronik/fjarrstyrning/433-mhz-sandarmodul-p88901) and the [receivers were these](http://www.nexa.se/PE3-komplett-set.htm). (unfortunately all in Swedish) But it seems like many of these devices behave similarly and with minor modifications can be controlled from Pi.

Comment: Please embed links into the text. As an active user you should already know about this.

Comment: So in short: i first receive the data with a receiver, see what it's like, and the send that same data. The 'Audacity' is new for me, so i'm not sure if i can get that to work to read data from the gpio...

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The idea to use audacity as an oscilloscope was new to me also, but was not that hard to get working.

Comment: Eventually i found this code http://pastebin.com/aRipYrZ6 which worked